# Good Design Pattern for C# Calculation Engines

Tags: c#-4.0, design-patterns

I am creating a calculation engine, calculation has 4 levels

1. LevelA1 , A2
2. LevelB
3. LevelC
4. LevelD

To calculate LevelA2 we need to calculate LevelD first and to calculate LevelD we need LevelC first output first and LevelB we need LevelA1.

Now During the calculation several intermediary values will be calculated at each level which we need to output at the end of calculations.

There are around 50 input fields(a collection of these fields) and almost similar count for the calculation output fields.

I would like to know a design pattern which is a best fit in this case.
Few specific question:

- During the calculations should I keep updating the input list during the calculations and output it since, final output is combination of inputs and outputs.
- or Should I have separate classes for each level of outputs and pass that output to the next level as we progress?

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: Are you bound to c#? If not then it might be worth considering F#, as a functional language it is way better suited to your needs and it integrates vary well with c# because they are both supported by .net.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most suitable pattern for this case will be Command pattern.
You can find a lot of examples of this pattern. I provide to you one of these.

[Command pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of all the components are same then

[Composite Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/composite-design-pattern)

If you need history or record in each level

[Command Pattern](https://www.dofactory.com/net/command-design-pattern)

If you want to devide all the responsibility in different classes then

[Chain of Responsibility](https://www.dofactory.com/net/chain-of-responsibility-design-pattern)

If you want Total complexity inside a wrap then

[Facade](https://www.dofactory.com/net/facade-design-pattern)

In this case if the calculation dependency is changing I would suggest to make a class for component and keep a member variable collection of component i.e. use composite pattern. Every subcomponent calculation will be contributed to total component result.

Here is the structure roughly

```
    class sample
{
    int data;
    list<sample> childList;
    int resultUptoThisPosition;
    bool ifResultCalculatedUptoThisPosition;
    void calculateresult()
    {
        int childResult = 0;
        forall(var clild in childList)
        {
            if(child.ifResultCalculatedUptoThisPosition == false)
            {
                child.calculateresult();
            }
            childResult+=resultUptoThisPosition;
        }
        resultUptoThisPosition += childResult; // own result is calculated from child result
        ifResultCalculatedUptoThisPosition = true; // calculation is done
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!!! pcBabu. How do I return the calculation result of LevelD to LevelC and LevelC to LevelB  etc.. should I return the Result object from each level to it's parent level? In most of the eaxamples it's void, not sure if it's by design. Also I want all the result of LevelD, C , B in Results of LevelA, my main method will make call to LevelA only. So should I just return the result from each level to it's parent and finally to main method?

Comment: Here in the description https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/composite doThis must return of his child calculation with his own calculation. If you want to make it void than you can add another member variable like result uptothis address and use a flag variable if that stage is callculated. Everytime you will find flag variable is emply then calculate more depth.